# Motherboard with 4 pin ATX 12 connector, and power-supply with cable split 4+4, which pair?

Tags: motherboard

I have a motherboard (Asus A88xm-e) and powersupply which is the Fanless Prime 600w.

The power supply has a cable for the ATX 12 connector (the connector is near the cpu) but has 8 pin instead of 4, the first "pair" has letter CP, the second pair U, I have to put the first pair or the second, or is the same thing?

Here you can see the connector (Page 1-16 aka page 24.)

- https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketFM2/A88XM-E/E9125_A88XM-E.pdf

This is the cable:

- https://www.ldlc.com/it-it/scheda/PB00371310.html

Both "pairs" has 4 pin in same order so both fit.

Documentation image (Page 1-16 aka page 24.):

> [image: Documentation image.]

Cable image:

> [image: Cable image.]

Comment: They're the same, but not physically. Pay close attention.

Comment: It's just 'the one that fits'.

Comment: Both fits, this is the problem

Comment: What page of that 66 page manual am I supposed to look at?

Comment: Page 24, I edit the message now

Comment: @elbarna There is no clear page 24. I assume it is page “1-16” and placed a screenshot. If this is not correct, please replace the image with the correct one.

Comment: Image is correct

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

I think one of the "pair" is okay, but for safety I plug the "first" pair which is the left one with the letter U, the other one has letter CP.